# composite stretch layered image

Tags: php, imagemagick

how can I layer one smaller image on another larger image, and then stretch the smaller image to get the same dimension as the other?

tmp.png is 210*22px

bg.png is 10*22px

composite bg.png tmp.png tmp.png

Answer (score 0):

Use [imagecopyresampled](http://docs.php.net/imagecopyresampled)! Read the user comments on the linked page if you have trouble with transparency.